# Symfony 2 404 Custom page for missing resource

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

So, I have been trying to add a 404 controller in case an image is missing and I need to go and get it.

Initially, I tried a NotFoundHttpException/ResourceNotFoundException listener which loaded a class to deal with it. This worked great, if it was a Symfony2 routing issue.

Problem is, it isn't. It is a /web/bundles/mysite/images/missingimage.jpg 404, which is handled by Apache it seems.

So with .htaccess I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]

    ErrorDocument 404 /web/404.txt
</IfModule>
```

Just to see if I could get that to work, but I get the feeling it wouldn't and it didn't.

So how can I get my setup to forward to a Symfony2 page when it encounters a 404 within the /web folder.

I am guessing it should be .htaccess, but I am not having much look.

In the end, I want it to go to:

```
/web/app.php/FourZeroFourHandler/web/bundles/mysite/images/missingimage.jpg
```

or:

```
/web/app_dev.php/FourZeroFourHandler/web/bundles/mysite/images/missingimage.jpg
```

Depending on whether I am in prod or dev.

And ideas?

Comment: Have you seen: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#customizing-the-404-page-and-other-error-pages

Comment: Sadly, no Symfony 404 is being thrown. Images are outside of Symfony2 routing, thus won't throw a NotFoundHttpException. It bypasses Symfony 2 all together and the only thing which knows about the 404 is Apache. Which is why I am trying to get Apache to go to a specific Routed URL if a 404 is hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

First one is to route all images via your Symfony2 app. The [LiipImagineBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle) does this in order to generate thumbnails. Like that you could redirect all `404` to your custom error page. Downside would be that even for a static image the whole Symfony2 kernel needs to be booted. That's time and resource expensive.

The second option is to redirect from Apache2 to a route that is unknown or to a route that throws a `404` / `HttpNotFoundException`:

```
/*
 * @Route('/404', name="not_found")
 */
public function notFoundAction()
{
    return new HttpNotFoundException();
}
```

That gives you more control over the error message since you can render a twig template or log an error message.

---

You are right. I also had some trouble with the custom controller when I inserted `ErrorDocument` in my `.htaccess`. The solution is to edit your `vhost` instead. Go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and select the file (by default it's called `default`) where your *virtual host* ist stored. Replace the `AllowOverride` option in the `<Directory>`. And replace it with these lines:

```
   AllowOverride FileInfo
   ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.html
```

Solution was found [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133622). Don't forget to reload your apache configuration:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: I would settle for Apache to just redirect 404's to a controller route. At the moment, ErrorDocument 404 doesn't seem to work. Having looked around the webs a bit, I was getting the impression that it wouldn't work for Symfony 2.

Comment: It does work. In my example redirect to `/404`. In your `.htacces` you need this entry: `ErrorDocument 404 /404`

Comment: As I mentioned above, I have this in my .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 /web/404.txt that 404.txt file does exist there. It is not shown when I try and access an image which isn't there. It is currently the last line within: IfModule mod_rewrite.c (I had that in my original post, but it was sat within &lt; &gt; and got removed. Any suggestions as to why it might not be working?

Comment: Seems like it is more an apache question. Check [this on Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/a/331984/174598) and see if it helps you. Also check your log-files. Also re-add your `.htaccess` in a proper format to your question please.

Comment: It is the default .htaccess in the web folder of Symfony. Nothing changed. Just wondering whether AllowOverride withing Apache has something to do with it. As that allows you to set ErrorDocument? Not sure if that is true or what it is currently set at. Updated my original post with full .htaccess